# Remove or Hide JScrollPane bug

Tags: java, swing

I have this program that has a button where it can bring data from database. The thing is it has to check the database for data. If there is data, then it displays it in a form of a Table. If not, shows a message (in JLabel) that no data exists. So far, so good. The issue is, after viewing the table, and then remove all data from database, it shows there is no data that exists. But, the table is still there. I can still see it, And it refuses to be removed. Why?

Here's Code:

```
else if(ae.getSource()==Test)
{

    try
    {   

        JTable table = new JTable();

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);


        String query="SELECT * FROM Students ORDER BY StdID";
        rs=st.executeQuery(query);

        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
            model.addColumn("No."); 
            model.addColumn("StdID"); 
            model.addColumn("StdName");
            model.addColumn("StdMajor");
            model.addColumn("StdGender");
            model.addColumn("StdAge");
            model.addColumn("StdEmail");
            model.addColumn("StdPhone");
            model.addColumn("RegisteredBy");
            model.addColumn("UpdatedBy");


            int result=0;



            int stdid;
            String stdname;
            String stdmajor;
            String stdgender;
            int stdage;
            String stdemail;
            String stdphone;
            String registeredby;
            String updatedby;

            while(rs.next())
            {

                result = result + 1;

                stdid = rs.getInt("StdID");
                stdname = rs.getString("StdName");              stdname = stdname.trim();
                stdmajor = rs.getString("StdMajor");            stdmajor = stdmajor.trim();
                stdgender = rs.getString("StdGender");          stdgender = stdgender.trim();
                stdage = rs.getInt("StdAge");
                stdemail = rs.getString("StdEmail");            stdemail = stdemail.trim();
                stdphone = rs.getString("StdPhone");            stdphone = stdphone.trim();
                registeredby = rs.getString("RegisteredBy");    registeredby = registeredby.trim();
                updatedby = rs.getString("UpdatedBy");


                if (!rs.wasNull())
                {   updatedby = updatedby.trim();   }

                else
                {   updatedby = ""; }


                DisplayStatus.setText(stdname);
                model.addRow(new Object[] { result, stdid, stdname, stdmajor, stdgender, stdage, stdemail, stdphone, registeredby, updatedby });

            }


            if(result>0)
            {

                DisplayStatus.setText("");


                JPanel LeftGap = new JPanel();
                    LeftGap.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    LeftGap.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 0)); 

                JPanel RightGap = new JPanel();
                    RightGap.setBackground(Color.WHITE);                    
                    RightGap.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 0));        


                JPanel BottomGap = new JPanel();
                    BottomGap.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    BottomGap.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 20));



                table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(10);      // No. Column                    
                table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(35);      // StdID Column     
                table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(30);      // StdMajor Column
                table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(30);      // StdGender Column
                table.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(10);      // StdAge Column
                table.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(130);     // StdEmail Column
                table.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(50);      // StdPhone Column


                DisplayTab.add(LeftGap, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
                DisplayTab.add(RightGap, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
                DisplayTab.add(BottomGap, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
                DisplayTab.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        }


        if(result <= 0)
        {
            //DisplayTab.remove(scrollPane);
            scrollPane.setVisible(false);

            DisplayStatus.setText("<html> <body bgcolor=C6C4C4> <font color=red style=font-size:35> There is no data in the database. </font> </body> </html>");
            DisplayStatus.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            DisplayStatus.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

            DisplayTab.revalidate();
            DisplayTab.repaint();


        }
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
```

**UPDATE #1 :**  I added full event code.

Comment: Are you processing the data from the database on the swing thread?

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: @ferrybig I'm a beginner, I don't know what you mean. All the database code deriving is in an ActionListener. (In the `Test` button.)

Comment: In short, give us enough code that runs and shows the problem.

Comment: @EricG is the whole `test` button event code enough?

Comment: @Nizar You should really learn how to debug properly. The less code you have to look at the more obvious the bug. In this case you can try to remove all table code (and just make a single cell with the number of results), as well as most of the DB reading code. That would leave you with some 20-odd lines, and it would be so much easier for both you and us to read it and find the error.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. It messes up the code highlighting in the forum. Follow the [Java Conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java).

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
```

Don't create a new JScrollPane. Add the scrollpane to the frame when you create the GUI.

Then when you want to change the component displayed in the scrollpane you just use:

```
scrollPane.setViewportView( theComponent );
```

Comment: Props for reading through that badly formatted mess and noticing that the wrong scroll pane is being removed.

Comment: @camickr
`JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.setViewportView(table); // If there is a result.
scrollPane.setViewportView(DisplayStatus); // If there is no result.`

It works perfectly with the table, but it doesn't show the DisplayStatus at all.

Comment: @Nizar, you are still doing something wrong. Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. So create a JFrame with an empty scrollpane. Then add two buttons to the panel. One button will display a text field and the other button will display the label. Learn the basic concect of how to use the `setViewportView(...)` method. Once you get is working in a simple program, you fix your real program.

Comment: @camickr Thanks for the help. I will give it a try.

Comment: @camickr I think I identified some stuff. After deleting and adding, the table doesn't refresh. It keeps itself the same way until I restart the program. Once I restart, it refreshes. Also, I forgot to close database connection on each event. Could that created such issues?

Answer (score 0):

All i know is that having remove before setVisible will make setvisible not work.

```
if(result <= 0)
{
    //DisplayTab.remove(scrollPane); not needed
    scrollPane.setVisible(false);

    DisplayStatus.setText("<html> <body bgcolor=C6C4C4> <font color=red style=font-size:35> There are no data in the database. </font> </body> </html>");
    DisplayStatus.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    DisplayStatus.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

    DisplayTab.revalidate();
    DisplayTab.repaint();

}
```

Comment: Oh, my bad. I tried removing it, and I tried hiding it. They both didn't work. I forgot that I put them both in here. Anyways, thanks for your reply, but same issue is still showing.

Comment: While true, this doesn't really influence the question in any way, nor does it answer it.